# How can I populate a table in one month increments based on a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, variables, datediff

I need to load a table based on the entry date from another table being between the 1st day of a month and the last day of the month. I need to decrement the load to be 1 month's worth of records 1 month from the current month, then 2 months from the current month and so so.

I've tried CTE, using a cursor, and manually changing the datediff parameters. This last method works, but I would like to load the table dynamically

```
Declare @StartDt as datetime = (SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(s,0,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-1,0)),'MM/dd/yyyy'));

Declare @endDt as datetime = EOMONTH(@StartDt);

SELECT  useruid, 
    userfullname,
    sum(totaltime)SumTime,
    @StartDt as StartDate, 
    @EndDt as EndDate

FROM Table_1.tbl
WHERE ENTRYDATE between @StartDt  and @EndDt
group by useruid, USERFULLNAME;
```

I am inserting this into another table. I don't have an issue doing that by manually changing -1 in the Startdt variable to -2 and so on. I want to know if I can have it change dynamically while loading the other table.

Again, I have no issues loading the table. I just want to know if there is a more efficient way to do so as I have to go back 100 months.

Comment: I don't understand - you're filtering for where the month is any day in the month and then going back 1 month at a time but inserting into same table. Why can't you just load all 100 months at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL to write your @StartDt declare statement on the fly.

I put your code in the while loop which will run 100 times. (go back 100 months):

```
declare @int int = 0
while @int > -100
begin
set @int= @int -1
declare @str varchar(max)
set @str = 'declare @StartDt as datetime = (SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(s,0,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())'+cast(@int as varchar(10))+',0)),''MM/dd/yyyy''))'
execute (@str)

Declare @endDt as datetime = EOMONTH(@StartDt)

SELECT  useruid, 
    userfullname,
    sum(totaltime)SumTime,
    @StartDt as StartDate, 
    @EndDt as EndDate

FROM Table_1.tbl
WHERE ENTRYDATE between @StartDt  and @EndDt
group by useruid, USERFULLNAME
end
```

Comment: Thank you also Gen Wan, I got your suggestion working as well

Comment: @mcedave You are welcome. The recursive CTE solution is much better than mine. (That's why I vote up Gordon's answer). But I hope my solution could give you some new idea.

Answer (score 1):

One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(month, -1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte > ?  -- how far back do you want to go?
     )
select t.useruid, t.userfullname, sum(t.totaltime) as SumTime,
       d.dte as StartDate, 
       dateadd(month, 1, d.dte) as EndDate
from dates d JOIN
     Table_1.tbl t
     on t.ENTRYDATE >= d.dte AND
        t.ENTRYDATE < dateadd(month, 1, d.dte) 
group by t.useruid, t.USERFULLNAME, d.dte;
```

You do not need a (an explicit) loop or a cursor.

Note:  You seem to be subtracting one second from the date for some reason.  I don't understand why.  You may need this logic for end date, but it is better to use the inequalities that are in the `on` clause (so you don't have to worry about milliseconds, for instance).

Comment: Thanks so much Gordon, this works great. I think I see where I went wrong on my CTE. I just had to make one minor tweak. This currently has the end date as the first day of the next month. I need the end date to be the last day of the start date month. I changed dateadd(month, 1, d.dte) as EndDate to EOMONTH(dte) as EndDate.

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense - you don't seem to need every month in that range, what are you achieving by this and not merely filtering for a range of 100 months?

Comment: @mcedave . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  This seems like the best solution to me.